# Errors changing column dtype to numeric

Tags: python, data-science-model

I am working with data from the government regarding COVID immunization numbers and would like to convert object columns into numeric. I am using Python in Jupyter Notebook. I tried using `to_numeric`, but the dtype is still an object. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the *errors* parameter of the to_numeric function to 'coerce'. The value 'ignore' will leave any invalid value as is while 'coerce' will set it to NaN.